# Need separate url from single page

Tags: html, url

i have a single page with multiple product categories. Can anyone guide how can i have separate url for each product category without creating different pages. Separate url will give me chance to optimise my each product category .

For references you can check http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-product.html

Kindly help

Comment: It appears to already be setup this way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the whole URL without redirecting, if you have a single page, I would suggest adding a hash to the URL which would make your page URl look something like http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-product.html#dyes. To do this, simply add the following javascript to the button onclick listener

```
document.location.hash = "dye_colors";
```

Comment: I don't think so, I just checked on Chrome and I don't see any hashes following the URL.

Comment: Oh, there are for firefox

Comment: Which browser are you checking this for, @Click n Join?

Comment: But is hash in url recommended for seo.. as i read in google for seo dont use hash in url.

Comment: No it's not recommended for SEO, if you are trying to force a URL, you will have to use mod_rewrite RewriteRule, on the server-side. Its done in a file using .htaccess, check this link: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @cyber_rookie - how do i separate each product category then

Comment: You could rewrite your URL from http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-product.html to, say http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-product-dyes.html or http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-products/dyes.html, there are endless possibilities.